# How to add a variable as custom launch option?

Tags: environment-variables, file-shortcut, error-correction

An error occurred when I used a system variable I set like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Exampleapp\examplefoleder\Example.exe"%variable%

Comment: what happens when you insert a space after the last quote, immediately before the %

Comment: "An error occurred " - What error exactly?  Instead of submitting a comment, edit your question, so an proper detailed answer can be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is most probably something like:

[image]

This is because if `variable` contains, for example, the value of `file.txt`
the command after substitution will look like:

```
notepad.exefile.txt
```

Windows will not be able to find a file named `notepad.exefile.txt`.

To fix this, leave a blank between the executable and its argument.